# Why do i get "Insufficient storage" when the so called "usb storage" is almost empty?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, internal-sd, usb-storage

Samsung Galaxy S2 is the model
I get no free space error msg when i try to install application from Google Play.
So i navigate to Settings->Storage and i see 3 sections:

- Device memory - 200MB Free
- USB Storage - 11.1GB FREE
- SD Card - 413MB FREE

Why cant the phone install it on the usb storage?

Comment: Detail your problem

Comment: Because you can't install to USB storage.

Comment: Apps can only be installed on Device internal memory and on SD Cards. Move large apps on SD Card

Answer (score 0):

External application cant install on usb memory as it is a external memory of your phone so you have to empty your phone memory stuff which may be songs, pics or the items which can store on external memory so that your application will install. or simply unistall the unwanted applications. It will help you to free internal memory